# Duplication of Previous and Next in jquery datatables.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am having two problem with the following jquery datatable.js . Firstly when I added my button Again previous and text is diplaying from the datatable.js  See the image so that you can understand clearly

And Secondly How i set my design in place of page no. See the image for clear understanding

And my code as follows :

Javascript:

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.datatable-1').dataTable();
   $('.dataTables_paginate').addClass("pagination pull-right");
   $('.pull-right > a').wrapInner('<span />');
   $('.pull-right > a:first-child').append('<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>');
   $('.pull-right > a:last-child').append(' <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>');
  } );
 </script>
```

And my style html code is of NEXT 1 2 3 ... PREVIOUS is

```html
 <ul class="pagination pull-right">
              <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
              <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
              <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
              <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
              <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Currently how its displaying is:
[Please View the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwN2F.png)

Thirdly I displayed both How it should look likes and how its looking now.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: The good question is: What are you trying to achieve? What is the purpose of doing that ...?

Comment: Because i want to my previous and next button is customized.

Comment: Why not change the buttons as needed in pure CSS, as in this ugly example -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/930/** ...?